# A generic CPU non blocking way to handle while loop in C

Tags: c, multithreading, while-loop, nonblocking

I would ask a very generic question that has been perplexing me for some time.
Very, very often we have to wait for the results from non-blocking functions, for example bytes to read from a file, socket or device.

Why waste the godsend of non-blocking functions for a blocking while?

So, is it possible, at least in POSIX API, to do a sort of `while(!somethingToRead()) forceToPassToNextJobInScheduler();`?

I can't find information about this anywhere, and it would be beautiful to limit the use of threads.

The fact that I have not found anything suggests to me that either I have not used the right keywords or that nothing similar is possible. But it would be wonderful, I hope.

Comment: This is normally done using `select()` or `epoll()`.

Comment: This is usually referenced in the corresponding POSIX manuals to the used functions.

Comment: Since you call out C in the question title, you should not add the C++ tag, unless you particularly like downvotes.

Comment: The loop you describe is precisely what a blocking function does.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, through your comment I'm studying a generic way to use POSIX functions combined with experimental libvpoll package

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is the result of wrong teachings, evidently: teachers said that I/O requests could release the job from execution.

Comment: @rikicecchi I don't know what you mean by "the job". What job are you talking about exactly?

Comment: On low level systems, such as when implementing your own simple scheduler similar to RTOS, the key is to use `if(function())` rather than `while(function())`. If the non-blocking function isn't ready, it should then return a code telling as much. And then you can optionally spend the rest of the time slice doing something else.

Comment: This is just as note: this is the most hated question that I ever made. Nonetheless, for me it's a interesting summary about the argument of multithreading. Even if you hated me for this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to the question thanks the researcher behind libvpoll: the exactly function that I'm talking about with '`forceToPassToNextJobInScheduler`' is `sched_yield()`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html

I'm pretty gone near to the solution, having open a tab aboust sched functions: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html
But as not a low-level POSIX expert, it's difficult to find easily the right solution.

Comment: P.S. I'm pretty disappointed by some-called C/C++ expertises.

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed that you feel that polling and sched_yield is a good design:(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this. This is *already* what blocking does. When your process is blocked, the scheduler automatically runs the next job/process/thread that is not blocked.

If you write a loop like this, the only difference will be that the scheduler *thinks* your thread isn't blocked, and it will keep switching back to your thread and then your thread will keep switching back the the scheduler - a waste of time.

Better to use actual blocking, and then the scheduler will know your thread is blocked, and won't run it until it's unblocked.

> Why waste the godsend of non-blocking functions for a blocking while?

You don't. To make good use of non-blocking functions you have to write your *entire program* in a non-blocking way, probably using a `struct` per connection *instead of* a thread, and something like [`epoll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) to see which connections have new data.

Comment: How could the OS recognize a blocking loop?

Comment: @rikicecchi It can't. It thinks your code is doing something useful, so it schedules your code. If you use blocking, then the OS *knows* your code is just waiting, so it *doesn't* schedule your code until it finishes blocking